# Stop meteor iron-router auto rendering template

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

My route:

```
Router.route('/profile/:_id', {
    layout:     'appTabs',
    template:   'appProfile',
    autoRender: false
  });
```

My Layout:

```
<template name="appTabs">
...
<a href="/profile/{{getUserId}}">
...
<section>
    {{> yield}}
  </section>
...
</template>
```

My Template:

```
<template name="appProfile">
  <section>
    <div>my profile</div>
  </section>
</template>
```

Trouble is that my route automatically renders. I have a link in my template, I want to wait for it to be clicked before the template is rendered. How do I achieve this?